gRPC with Microsoft AuthenticationStateProvider problems
I recently set up a new gRPC Project, containing simple a Server, Client and Contract Sub-Project.
Server will be deployed as a WebService, Client is goind to be an android app.
Contract containing the proto-files for server/client.
So far, basic communication with channel and client is working fine.
Currently I need to implement some special kind of session handling, because the service needs to talk to an API that has it's on connection and connection-object.
Now my conusion, or maybe just missunderstanding, starts.
I have a Login-Service that creates the API connection with given credentials and also creates a UserSession-Object that I want to manage on server-side, to verify every follow-up request from that channel/session.
I wanted to use the default AspNetCore Authorization and create my own AuthenticationStateProvider.
Trying to map the provider on startup, resolves in an 'Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' in the application startup code.'.
Calling given 'AddAuthorization' resolves in an 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware'.'.
So I'm a little bit lost here in how to achieve an authorization, that is checking current available sessions if there is any session that fits the request-metadata sessionid/token, without needing to implement it specificly/manually for every method.
Server Startup currently looking like this:
using GrpcTesting.Services;
using GrpcTesting.Services.Live;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc(options =>
{
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; // theoretisch sollte dass dafür sorgen, das wir die konkrete Exception bekommen
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, MobileAuthenticationStateProvider>();
//builder.Services.<AuthenticationStateProvider, MobileAuthenticationStateProvider>();
//builder.Services.add

//builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRouting();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseGrpcWeb(new GrpcWebOptions() { DefaultEnabled = true });

app.MapGrpcService<TestService>().EnableGrpcWeb();

app.MapGet("/", ()
    => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();


I tried the default attributes [AllowAnynomous] and [Authorize], which do work and allow or block a request without any specific authorization. But I lack the understanding of 'how' and 'where' to implement the dedicated authorization, that should be executed when a method has the [Authorize] attribute.
Any help or suggestions would be welcome.
